# Hibernate, indirect relations mapping

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, relational-database

I have two tables: Word and Stems. The second one has field which is a foreign key to Word. So many stems can belong to one word.

In Java I created Entities Word and Stem. Because word can have many stems and I have some operations on list of this stems I decidec to put this list with correspond method in separate class called Stems. Object of this class is in Word entity. Below I present how my code looks like:

---

**Word.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Word")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public abstract class Word implements Serializable{

    // primary key and other columns

    @Transient
    protected Stems stems = new Stems();

    public void setStems(List<Stem> stems) {
        this.stems.setStems(stems);
    }

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="word")
    public List<Stem> getStems() {
        return stems.getStems();
    }
}
```

**Stems.java**

```
public class Stems {

    private List<Stem> stems = new ArrayList<>();

    public List<Stem> getStems() {
        return stems;
    }

    public void setStems(List<Stem> stems) {
        this.stems = stems;
    }
}
```

**Stem.java**

```
@Entity  
@Table(name = "Stems")  
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)  
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="Type",discriminatorType=DiscriminatorType.STRING)  
public abstract class Stem implements Cloneable{

    @Id
    @Column(name = "Stem", unique = true, nullable = false, length = 64)
    private String rawStem;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "WordId", nullable = false)
    private Word word;
}
```

---

And here come my questions. Is it possible to make a HQL query to get word with proper stems? If no then how achieve this. Maybe this structure isn't allowed to work? How can I add/update words with stems? I tried set array of stems in word and word id in each stem and then use session.merge(word) but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw the light. I'd like to paste here complete solution to my problem. This solution allows to modify Stems table only by calling session.merge on word object which contain list of stems.

Pleas note annotations **@Embedded**, **@Embeddable** and parameter **orphanRemoval** in **@OneToMany** annotation.

---

**Word.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Word")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)  
public abstract class Word implements Serializable{

    // primary key and other columns

    @Embedded
    protected Stems stems = new Stems();

    public List<Stem> getStems() {
        return stems.getStems();
    }

    public void setStems(List<Stem> stems) {
        this.stems.setStems(stems);
    }
}
```

**Stems.java**

```
@Embeddable
public class Stems {
    // orphanRemoval removes stems which is present in database but not on list
    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy="word", orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<Stem> stems = new ArrayList<>();

    // getters/setters
}
```

**Stem.java** - no changes.